# Auth::attempt [Laravel] doesn't work well,, It's always return false

Tags: php, authentication, laravel, controllers

every time I try to Test my TestLogin function it return false, whether my inputs were uncorrect[not stored in DataBase] or correct [that stored in my DataBase] ...

config of auth.phph correct that [ 'model' => 'User'&& 'table' => 'users']

Please any help here :)

public function TestLogin()
    {

```
    $data = Input::All();                     //Get Input with POST Request
    $UNameOrEmail = $data['UnameOrEmail'];
    $password = $data['Password'];

    if(filter_var($UNameOrEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {      //Check if Input Is Email or else(then consider it as user name)

        $validator = Validator::make(           //Validation for Email
            array(
                'email' => $UNameOrEmail,
                'password' => $password,
            ),
            array(
                'email' => 'required|email|exists:users,email',
                'password' => 'required|min:8'
            )
        );

        if ($validator->fails()) { //If Email Validation was wrong return validation message
            $messages = $validator->messages();
            return $messages;
        }
        else                           //else store Email&Password in Array
            $user = array(
                'email' => $UNameOrEmail,
                'password' => Hash::make($password)
            );

    }

    else {
        $validator = Validator::make(    //Check User Name Validation
            array(
                'user_name' => $UNameOrEmail,
                'password' => $password,
            ),
            array(
                'password' => 'required|min:8',
                'user_name' => 'required|alpha_dash|between:4,16'
            )
        );

        if ($validator->fails()) {                  //If User Name Validation was wrong return validation message
            $messages = $validator->messages();
            return $messages;
        } else
            $user = array(                           //else store UserName&Password in Array
                'user_name' => $UNameOrEmail,
                'password' => Hash::make($password)
            );

    }


    if (Auth::attempt($user)) {             //Here's the Error

        echo 'Successfully logged in';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Some thing go wrong';             //In any case it jum here :(
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you show your user model?  Specifically the functions named `getAuthIdentifier()` and `getAuthPassword()`?

Comment: protected $table = 'users';


    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not hash the password before passing it to `Auth::attempt`. Just pass the plain password:

```
$user = array(                           
    'user_name' => $UNameOrEmail,
    'password' => $password
);
```

Also make sure that you store a hash of the password in the database and the password field is **60 characters long**. Otherwise the hash will be truncated and it won't work.

Comment: just tried it,, but same result come ..

I've inserted a record in database and take email & password cpy&paste to test mu code ,, but always return false

Comment: Is the password in the database hashed? And is the field at least 60 characters long so the hash doesn't get truncated?

Comment: I've inserted a email & password manually then comment this line //'password' => Hash::make($password) instead put this one 'password' => $password ...

but same wrong :(

Comment: You can't just manually insert a password. It has to be hashed. Use `artisan tinker` and then `echo Hash::make('secret');` then copy the output into your db

Comment: ok i've edit code and removed Hash::make($password); to be just 'password => $password ,,and yes password in database hashed, but no thing is changed :/

Comment: Is that what you mean : $2y$10$jTNbWE3SCcqoMyO6ZfbpRu7g63CKmUiyg.Lvfc

Comment: Thanks. now I see what the problem is. The hash is to short. This is most certainly due a db field that's too short. (45 characters) the password field has to be **60 characters long**

Comment: Ok,, I'll try longer password and till you the result :)

Comment: Just to be sure you understood right. Not a longer password but a longer password **field** in the database.

Comment: yeah I found that the length of password was just 45 not 60 ,,,

now it's work perfectly xD Thaaaaanx Mr/ @lukasgeiter ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I can see you are using Input::All() ( capital A ), instead of `Input::all()`.

Do a `dd(Input::All());` to see what it returns.

Found the problem ( I Think ): You shoud **NOT** Hash your password, since Auth does it automatically. So in short, you are hashing it manualy and then Auth hashes it again and that is why password never matches what is stored in the DB table :)

Comment: In PHP class and function names are case insensitive. So while it does look wrong it still works to call `Input::All()`

Comment: No no [Input::All();] get same result as Input::all();

that's the result of dd(Input::All()); >> 

    array(2) {
    ["UnameOrEmail"]=>
    string(21) "m.hamdy1994@gmail.com"
    ["Password"]=>
    string(8) "12345678"
    }

Comment: whether Input::All(); or Input::all(); it still get same result after using print with dd(Input::All()); or dd(Input::all());

Now i insert a record using app and removed >> Hash::make($password); from my code but no thing new still get same message